# API - Update Asset Volume

Tags: assets, craft3, element

Im trying to figure out how to move asset(s) to a different volume. Also if I move it will that affect the entries that are using the asset?

Here's what im using to target the asset:
`$resourceImage = Asset::find()->volume('resourceImages')->filename($filename);`

I need to move it to my `productImages` volume.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can move them like this

```PHP
$asset = Asset::find()->volume('resourceImages')->filename($filename)->one()
$folder = Craft::$app->getAssets()->findFolder(['volumeId' => X]);
Craft::$app->getAssets()->moveAsset($asset, $folder, $filename);
```

It won't change your relations or anything else in fact all the function does is:

```PHP
/**
 * Move or rename an Asset.
 *
 * @param Asset $asset The asset whose file should be renamed
 * @param VolumeFolder $folder The Volume Folder to move the Asset to.
 * @param string $filename The new filename
 * @return bool Whether the asset was renamed successfully
 * @throws AssetLogicException if the asset’s volume is missing
 */
public function moveAsset(Asset $asset, VolumeFolder $folder, string $filename = ''): bool
{
    // Set the new combined target location, and save it
    $asset->newFilename = $filename;
    $asset->newFolderId = $folder->id;
    $asset->setScenario(Asset::SCENARIO_FILEOPS);

    return Craft::$app->getElements()->saveElement($asset);
}
```